# Matrix such that $4A^4+I=0$ must have integer trace.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, contest-math

Suppose that a real $n\times n$ matrix satisfies that $4A^4=-I$. Prove that its trace must be an integer. Is my solution correct?

> $A$ has $n$ complex eigenvalues with multiplicities, what can they be? if $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue then $4\alpha^4=-1$ so they can be $\pm\frac{1-i}{2}$ or $\pm\frac{1+i}{2}$. Since the matrix is real every eigenvalue appears the same number of times as its conjugate. Notice that in this case the sum of every eigenvalue and its conjugate gives $1$ or $-1$, we conclude the trace is an integer between $\frac{-n}{2}$ and $\frac{n}{2}$

Comment: Looks good, only the equation is $4\alpha^4 = -1$ and not $4\alpha^4 = 1$ (the roots are still good).

Comment: If $A$ is real, then characteristic polynomial is a real polynomial whose complex roots occur in conjugate pairs, so sum of roots is always a real number regardless of any identity satisfied by $A$. If you take $A$ to be complex matrix then obviously we have example where trace is not an integer. Take $A$ as diagonal matrix with each diagonal entry equal to $\frac{1-i}{2}$.